# SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain when using vscode Remote - Containers extension

Tags: git, ssl, visual-studio-code

I am using [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension of vscode. Following this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial#_get-the-sample), got error:

> Cloning into '/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-node'...
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-node/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

What I had tried is to set the `http.sslverify=false` global config for git by the below command:

```sh
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Tried again, but still got the same error.

Is there a setting for this extension so that I can disable the SSL certificate verify?